# Adding buttons to openbravo webpos (pda)

Tags: java, openbravo

Has anybody added buttons to the web pos (pda) of Openbravo POS 2.30
As i would like to add the button to print to kitchen, from the web and not only from the POS standalone client.

Thanks in advance

Note: i'm using the community version

Answer (score 0):

- I don't think anybody has done adding button to the **Web application PDA module** , 
  But this can be customized quickly since this is a j2ee web application with struts and jsp.
- I did not find any developer guide from openbavo side for this PDA Module customizations.
- **Web application PDA module** and Openbravo POS standalone are two different applications pointing to the single database server.So you may need to add buttons to both the applications.

[Openbravo POS/PDA Source Code](https://code.openbravo.com/pos/devel/main/file/0541e63fd59f)

Thanks,

Comment: Well i'm not conversant with Java/java-ee, but will learn it (I have a PHP/C++ background). Well i did search around and even posted on their forums, and no one replied.